# C# and ASP.NET: Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, encryption, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I've tried everything I found cross the web, but I couldn't figure out what is the problem. I have these methods to encrypt/decrypt strings:

```
public static class SecurityUtils {

    public static readonly string EncryptionKey = "my.key." + Guid.NewGuid();

    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
    public static string Encrypt(this string stringToEncrypt, string key) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToEncrypt)) {
            throw new ArgumentException("An empty string value cannot be encrypted.");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot encrypt using an empty key. Please supply an encryption key.");
        }

        var cspp = new CspParameters { KeyContainerName = key, Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore };

        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspp) { PersistKeyInCsp = true };

        byte[] bytes = rsa.Encrypt(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt), true);

        return BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
    }

    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
    public static string Decrypt(this string stringToDecrypt, string key) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToDecrypt)) {
            throw new ArgumentException("An empty string value cannot be encrypted.");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot decrypt using an empty key. Please supply a decryption key.");
        }

        var cspp = new CspParameters { KeyContainerName = key, Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore };

        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspp) { PersistKeyInCsp = true };

        var decryptArray = stringToDecrypt.Split(new[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var decryptByteArray = Array.ConvertAll(decryptArray, (s => Convert.ToByte(byte.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))));


        byte[] bytes = rsa.Decrypt(decryptByteArray, true);

        string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

        return result;
    }

}
```

I'm using this code for months in several projects and it seems perfect. Until a project I'm working on now. It works local just as I want to. But when I publish it to my server, I get this error:

> Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.

**Stack Trace:**

```
[CryptographicException: Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.] 
System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.DecryptKey(SafeKeyHandle pKeyContext, Byte[] pbEncryptedKey, Int32 cbEncryptedKey, Boolean fOAEP, ObjectHandleOnStack ohRetDecryptedKey) +0  
System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt(Byte[] rgb, Boolean fOAEP) +214    
myNamespace.SecurityUtils.Decrypt(String stringToDecrypt, String key) +260    
... the rest...
```

Do you have any idea please? Thanks in advance.